# Defining and plotting a two dimensional array for python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help getting an explanation on how to do the following problem:

> define a two dimensional array u(x,t)
>
> 1.spatial domain: x: [0º,360º], choose dx=5
>
> 2.temporal domain: t:[0s,120s], choose dt=0.5s
>
> 3.initial condition: when t=0, u(x,t=0)=sin(2x)

I tried doing what is below. I know it is wrong, but am I at least starting to get what I have to do? Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
t=(121)
x=(361)
u=(x,t)
dt=0.5
dx=5
  
arr = []
for i in range(360):
    u(x,t=0)= np.sin(np.radians(360)*2)
 
for j in range (120):
    u(x,t(n+1)*dt)=u(x,t=n*dt)+3*dt
```

Comment: You should follow some tutorials. You should probably read about numpy and matplotlib. Ask such question on StackOverflow is not encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy handles matrices in a simple way, in your case the main error is that you must create the matrix before using it. One possible solution is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

dt = 0.5
dx = 5

x = np.arange(0, 360+dx, dx)
t = np.arange(0, 120+dt, dt)

u_x = np.zeros((t.shape[0], x.shape[0]))
u_x[0] = np.sin(np.radians(2*x))

for i in range(len(t)-1):
    u_x[i+1] = u_x[i] + 3*dt

ts = [0, 1, 10, 60, 120]

for tx in [0, 1, 10, 60, 120]:
    plt.plot(u_x[int(tx/dt)], label="t={}seg".format(tx))
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, I went through it and I'm curious about why you didn't imbed the second for loop into the first one. Does this matter at all? Or are there generally multiple ways to get the same result?

Comment: @h.k. What do you mean by the second loop ?, the powerful numpy is that you can work with structures such as vectors and arrays in a simple way avoiding cumbersome loops generating a clean and clear code. Another thing, in SO is accustomed to give an upvote or mark a response as correct if this was of help.

Comment: The way that I understood it is that you need two for loops to make it 2D, and a lot of the examples I have seen to get to that is with it imbedded into the first one. so it would kind of look like "for I in range... and then on the next line it would have an equation that is indented, and then the following line is still indented and says for j in range... etc" so it's kind of a loop inside another loop. I didn't know if what you did was the same thing as what the other examples are doing but just in a different way

Comment: @h.k. I explain: the arange function creates a vector indicating the beginning, the end and the step, so I think x and t. Then create a data mesh that must have the size: length of x by length of and, for that case we use shape, zeros () creates a matrix filled with zeros where one has to indicate the size. u_x [i] is a mesh vector that shows the data for a certain time, so it iterates over the index i by applying the equation you have placed. Please mark my answer as correct, I have invested my time and I think that is what I should get.